# delphi combination algorithm

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Hello I cant write the combination algorithm. For example; I have 1 Red and 2 White balls and I want to write number red balls + number white balls. Like below;

```
R->Red
W->White

RWW
WRW  
WWR
```

totally 3 combinasion I have. But How can I write it in Delpi? Because, may be I have 10 RED 8 White or 15 RED 20 White etc.. How can I oreder this kombination.

I have one rules .

1- I have to use all balls eveytime. My order, combination Length has to be total ball. In my example it has to be 2+1=3.

how can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations#Delphi

Comment: Is it always an alphabet of length 2?

Comment: No length may be 10 15 20 2000 etc...

Comment: No, the alphabet length

Comment: alphabet length is 2.

Comment: @Nidhoegger I did but I see same value one more one.

Comment: @David Heffernan any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
procedure Combination( pLeft : string;pRedCount, pWhiteCount : integer; pResult : strings );
begin
  if (pRedCount = 0) and (pWhiteCount = 0)  then
  begin
    pResult.Add( pLeft );
    exit;
  end;
  if pRedCount > 0 then Combination( pLeft + 'R', pRedCount - 1, pWhiteCount, pResult );
  if pWhiteCount > 0 then Combination( pLeft + 'W', pRedCount, pWhiteCount - 1, pResult )

end;
```

For example if in your main program you had a TMemo called Memo, a spinedit called RCount and another called WCount, then on your action button you would execute

```
Memo.Lines.Clear
Combination( '', RCount.Value, WCount.Value, Memo.Lines );
```